# How to add a "+" symbol at the last value of react-native-slider?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating a slider with react-native-slider and i need to give it values from 0 to 10+.
It regularly works from 0 to 10, however i need to add a + symbol ONLY for the value 10, something like this "10+" how to do that?

```
<Slider
          style={styles.slider}
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={1}
          minimumTrackTintColor="#ff6700"
          maximumTrackTintColor="#999999"
          thumbTintColor="#ff6700"
          step={0.1}
          value= {1}
          onValueChange={value => setRange(parseInt((value * 10))) }
        />
```

Comment: `value => { const ran = parseInt(value * 10); setRange(ran === 10 ? "10+" : ran); }`